# I would like to add a query param apikey for all my external call

Tags: node.js, express

I have a server in express and it uses an external api. I would like for each request to that api ('/api/*'), that it appends a query param in the url without to write it for each requests.

```
app.use(function(req, res) {
    req.query.key = process.env.APIKEY;
});
```

I tried something like that but it doesn't work.

I thought of doing something like :

```
app.get('/api/stuff', addApiKey, api.stuff);
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply your middleware function with a `next` callback:

```
function addApiKey(req, res, next) {
    req.query.key = process.env.APIKEY;
    next();
});

app.get('/api/:endpoint', addApiKey, function(req, res) {
   // do your stuff here
});
```